# Поворот экрана - крашится приложение

Tags: android, экран

Сделал лейаут для обеих ориентаций. Не могу понять в чем причина, состояние пока не сохранял, для начала необходимо просто отрисовать интерфейс. Я так понимаю, теряются виджеты и активность не может их найти?

Вот лог:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                     
Process: com.hfad.test1, PID: 7695

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hfad.test1/com.hfad.test1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference                                                                 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2346)                                                                  
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)                                                                  
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3960)                                                                 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:144)                                                                
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)                                                                 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)                                                                  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5277)                                                                 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)                                                                 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:919)                                                                  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:714)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference                                                                  
at com.hfad.test1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)                                                                  
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5983)                                                                  
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)                                                                  
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)                                                                 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)                                                                   
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3960)                                                                   
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:144)                                                                   
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)                                                                   
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)                                                                 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5277)                                                                 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)                                                                  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:919)                                                                 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:714)
```

А вот код активности:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
private static final String TAG = "MyLogs";

int myCurrentPeriod = 1500;
private Timer myTimer;

private Button btnStop;
private Button btnStartPause;
private Button btnTest;

private TextView tv;
private TextView etName;

private String startStr;
private String pauseStr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v(TAG, "try to onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);

    btnStartPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartPause);
    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    btnTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);

    startStr = getResources().getString(R.string.btnStart);
    pauseStr = getResources().getString(R.string.btnPause);

    btnTest.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnStartPause.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(this);

    Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    //Уведомление о том, что будет запущена активность
    Log.v(TAG, "onRestart");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //Уведомление о том, что активность запускается
    Log.v(TAG, "onStart");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Уведомление о том, что активность будет взаимодействовать с пользователем
    Log.v(TAG, "onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //Уведомление о том, что активность прекращает взаимодействовать с пользователем
    Log.v(TAG, "onPause");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //Уведомление о том, что активность больше не видима
    Log.v(TAG, "onStop");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //Уведомление о том, что активность будет удалена
    if (myTimer != null) {
        myTimer.cancel();
    }
    Log.v(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //Сохранение состояния экземпляра
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.v(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //Восстановление состояни
    Log.v(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    etName.clearFocus();
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnStartPause:
            Button btn = (Button)v;
            String btnString = btn.getText().toString();
            if (btnString.equals(startStr)) {
                btnStartPause.setText(pauseStr);
                myTimer = new Timer();
                myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runTimer();
                    }
                }, 0, 1000);
                Log.v(TAG, "onStartClicked");
            } else if (btnString.equals(pauseStr)) {
                btnStartPause.setText(startStr);
                myTimer.cancel();
                Log.v(TAG, "onPauseClicked");
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnStop:
            if (myCurrentPeriod != 1500) {
                myTimer.cancel();
                myCurrentPeriod = 1500;
                tv.setText("25:00");
                Log.v(TAG, "onStopClicked");
            }
            btnStartPause.setText(startStr);
            break;
        case R.id.btnTest:
            myCurrentPeriod = 15;
            Log.v(TAG, "onTestClicked");
            break;
        default:
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            break;
    }
}

private void runTimer() {
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
    Log.v(TAG, "runTimer");
}

private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myCurrentPeriod--;
        int minutes = (myCurrentPeriod%3600)/60;
        int secs = myCurrentPeriod%60;
        String time = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, secs);
        tv.setText(time);
        if (myCurrentPeriod == 0) {
            myTimer.cancel();
            myCurrentPeriod = 1500;
            tv.setText("25:00");
            btnStartPause.setText(startStr);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BreakActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("task", etName.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
            Log.v(TAG, "start BreakActivity");
        }
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в разметке ошибка. У одной/всех кнопок нет/неправильный ID. Проеврьте ещё раз размету.

Comment: Вопрос снимается, не убрал устаревший метод _onClick_ в разметке для _-land_.